# Как убрать горизонтальный scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, веб-программирование, прокрутка, adaptive

Верстал пробный PSD макет, **адаптив** работал, но после добавления анимации(анимация при скролле) все сломалось. Появляется *горизонтальный scroll*, хотя блоки не вылезают за ширину контейнера. Подскажите пожалуйста что делать, как решить эту проблему? Вот **ссылка** - http://youyom.beget.tech/

Comment: добавить `div.wrapper` `overflow-x: hidden;`

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin спасибо огромное!!! Все заработало.

Comment: Сделай триггеры на отработку анимации (Какой-нибудь аттрибутик на элементе, обозначающий что он отработал (или отсутствие аттрибутика)), а то по несколько раз один и тот-же вылет - очень странно))